# D3 js orgchart plugin with mixed hierarchy

Tags: d3.js, hierarchical-data, orgchart

Is there any js plugin available to render mixed hierarchy like the attached image. 
I am looking for below features

1. on demand loading
2. mixed hierarchy
3. node customization
4. zooming and panning
5. json data support

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: orgchart]

GetOrgChart is exactly what you are looking for

[on demand loading](http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Performance-2000-nodes)

[node customization](http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Node-Customization)

[json data support](http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Initialize-From-JSON)

mixed hierarchy - it supports different of orientation for example from left to right or from bottom to top

zooming and panning - scroll up/down with the mouse and use the keyboard kes to navigate